# How and when did the word "Kollel" come to mean "an institution for paying scholars to study Torah"?

Tags: history, hebrew, etymology, language, yeshiva-school

How and when did the word "Kollel" come to mean "an institution for paying scholars to study Torah"?

If I'm not mistaken, the Hebrew word "kollel" means "includes."

But today we've all heard of the noun Kollel; "Shmerel learns at Rabbi Goldstein's Kollel."

How and when was that term coined?

Comment: I thought it just means "an institution for paying people to study Torah".

Answer (score 6):

Those that were helped were included in the booklet (Pinkas).

http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D

> ביישוב הישן, המונח כולל שימש לציין ארגוני חסד ובעיקר 'חברה' (או כיום
>   מעין עמותה) שאליה השתייכה קבוצה מאורגנת, בדרך כלל מעיר או ארץ מוגדרת.
>   יהודי חוץ לארץ תרמו להחזקת הכוללים, כדי לממן את ישיבתם של יהודים בארץ
>   ישראל. לרוב דאגו תושבי מקום בחו"ל לבני קהילתם שבארץ-ישראל, ולכן התפתחו
>   הארגונים לפי ארצות-מוצא. יהודי שעלה לארץ היה נרשם ב"פנקס" (כעין מיפקד)
>   של נציגי קהילתו בארץ, כדי שיהיה זכאי לסיוע מהם. **הכללתו בפנקס היא
>   שהעניקה את השם "כולל".** לדוגמה, יהודי הונגריה תרמו ל"כולל אונגרין"
>   והיהודים שעלו לארץ מהונגריה, שהיו כלולים ברשימה כחברי הקהילה ההונגרית,
>   קיבלו מהם כספי-חלוקה. על הכוללים מסוג זה נמנים כולל רייסין לעולי
>   רוסיה, כולל הולנד ודויטשלנד (כולל הו"ד) וכולל חיבת ירושלים (עבור יוצאי
>   גליציה שעלו לארץ ישראל).‏